# How do I conditionally render elements based off of path react.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, path, conditional-statements, rendering

So I'm creating a blog app with react.js and ruby on rails. I have these buttons that are in my nav component that I need to conditionally render based off of the path the user is in. I'm using `useLocation` to accomplish this and almost have it where I want it. The problem I'm having is getting them to render in the three main paths where posts can be seen ('/general', '/resources', & '/events') while hiding them when a user goes into a post to view the comments. The buttons will show up in those paths if I remove the /path/id but as I stated I need them not to render in the /path/id just the /path. How can I accomplish this?

```js
const [getAllPosts, setGetAllPosts] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        const res = await fetchAllPosts()
        setGetAllPosts(res.filter(post => {
          return post.category.title === 'general' || post.category.title === 'resources' || post.category.title === 'events'
        }))
      }
      fetchData()
    }, [])

return (   
{getAllPosts.forEach((generalPost, resourcePost, eventsPost) => {return location.pathname === '/user' || location.pathname === '/about' || location.pathname === '/create' || location.pathname === `/general/${generalPost.id}` || location.pathname === `/general/${resourcePost.id}` || location.pathname === `/general/${eventsPost.id}` ? (<></>) : (<div className={open ? 'RegisterContainerMobileOpen' : 'RegisterContainerMobile'}>
            {currentUser ? (
              <button onClick={handleLogout} className='logoutmobile'>Logout</button>
              ) : (
              <Link to='/user' className='resgisterlinkmobile'>
                <button className='registermobile'>Signin/Signup</button>
              </Link>
            )}
          </div>)})})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

If you need to see the rest of my code just let me know. I've been working day and night on this with little sleep so I feel I am missing something simple.

Edit: I've also tried using `.map()` but get back multiple instances of the same button since map returns a new array. I've looked into `React.memo` in my research, but I'm not fully sure how I'd use that or even if it would be a fix to the mapping issue

Note: after reading more documentation on `React.memo` it does not seem like that would help

Answer (score 1):

Without going too deeply into the task, try to add `return` and instead of `forEach` use `map`. Remember that `forEach` returns nothing, unlike `map`.

So it could look like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
...
}

return getAllPosts.map(...
```

Comment: So I did forget to mention I originally did use `.map()` however that would hide the original button but then re-render more buttons based off how many posts there were since map creates a new array. I was looking into `React.memo` to hopefully solve that but I'm not entirely sure how to use it or if that even would be a solution. How can I get around that issue?